# Using server session to publish reactive data

Tags: javascript, session, meteor, meteorite

I'm using the [matteodem:server-session](https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-server-session/) to store a session variable to publish data to populate a select form. The published data doesn't work correctly and is non reactive ie when the session var changes, values matching the previous result is shown. I've tried wrapping it into a tracker.autorun function directly but it didn't work *(I think this is where I goofed up in implementing)*. Could anyone please help me where I'm going wrong. Thanks!

SERVER side : server//publish.js

```
 Tracker.autorun(function () {
        Meteor.publish('locations', function() {
      return Locations.find({
           owner: ServerSession.get('id')
        });
    });
});
```

// Client side : this is how I store it

```
Template.rideItem.events({
     'click .rideid': function(){
        var rideid = this._id;       
        ServerSession.set('id', rideid)
    }
});
```

**PS**: Please bear if it is elementary, I'm just starting out with meteor, which is for sure amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Glad you enjoy Meteor. You don't need to set a server-side variable in order to keep communication active between the client and the server. You can use your above mentioned publish and send an `_id` to it such as:

```
Meteor.publish('locations', function(id) {
  return Locations.find({
      owner: id
  });
});
```

On the client use the regular Session to make your helpers reactive and subscribe with `Meteor.subscribe('locations', Session.get('id'));`

```
Template.rideItem.events({
     'click .rideid': function(){
        var rideid = this._id;       
        Session.set('id', rideid)
    }
});

Template.rideItem.helpers({
    location: function() {
      return Locations.find({owner: Session.get('id')});
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply mate! Actually the helper function belongs to a different template. I tried this approach but it didn't work.( I have a listing where each has a book option, I use the rideid of each listing to generate specific form fields for the listing on a new page)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make Meteor.publish reactive, in the sense you desire, just by wrapping it in Tracker.autorun. This is because the latter is a **client**-side package. Also, [matteodem:server-session](https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-server-session) is not a reactive data source. If you cannot implement your functionality on the client with regular [Session](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session), explore [cursor.observe](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe) and [cursor.observeChanges](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe_changes).